# Using pager of Jquery Cycle without using empty anchors

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

With the jquery cycle plugin, the pagers are expected to be in this sort of format.

```
<div id='nav'>
     <a href='#'>pager1</a>
     <a href='#'>pager2</a>
     <a href='#'>pager3</a>
     <a href='#'>pager4</a>
</div>
```

The thing that I don't like is using anchor links for things that aren't actually links... so I set up a custom pager creation function which essentially ends up looking something like ...

```
<div id="nav">
    <span class='pager'>Pager1</span>
    <span class='pager'>Pager2</span>
    <span class='pager'>Pager3</span>
    <span class='pager'>Pager4</span>
</div>
```

The problem ends up being that the spans aren't clickable.  So I'm wondering if there's an easily accessible way to have the spans be interactive just like the a's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, turns out it does work.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:     'fade', 
        timeout: 5000, 
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerEvent: 'click',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            //alert(text);
            return '#nav span:eq('+ index+')'; 
        }
    });
```